# Add custom HTML class property to selected block in a QTextEdit

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtextedit

I am not new to Qt, but I can't find how to add a custom css class to the selected block in a QTextEdit.

As far as I know,format is changed whit code like this:

```
QTextCursor cursor = textEdit->textCursor();
QTextBlockFormat bfmt;
// Apply format changes
cursor.setBlockFormat(bfmt);
```

When I do this, the generated HTML code creates a span with inlined style in it, but what I want is to insert the css class:

```
<SPAN class='myclass'>text</span>
```

I am missing a function inside QTextBlockFormat to set the css class of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to emulate this behavior by manually adding `<span style="">` tags to your selected text:

```
QString oldText = cursor.selectedText();
// not the best way to concat three strings, but for example only...
cursor.insertHtml(QString("<span class=\"%1\">%2</span>").arg("myclass").arg(oldText));
```

`selectedText()` will return currently selected text, and `insertHtml()` will insert new text at the beggining of the cursor, deleting current selection, if any.